# Delete commits after some dirty tests

Tags: git

I've found a bug in my scripts so I did a lot attempt to fix it.

I'm a Git beginner so what I did is probably dirty but I committed after each try on my master branch. so I can push the changes and try if it works on a remote machine.

Now everything is working fine but the master branch is a bit messy :

A -> B -> fix_attempt_1 -> fix_attempt_2 ->  ... -> fix_attempt_15 -> B_without_bug

I'd like to remove all the commits related to my tests so I can have a clean graph :

A -> B -> B_without_bug

My questions are

1. How can I do that ?
2. What is the best branching strategy to avoid this next time ? Create a test branch so I don't make tests on the master branch ?

Comment: `git rebase` seems to be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `git rebase -i` is your friend, but is **dangerous, since it will rewrite your history**. Anyone else using your branch (*master* in this case) will have references to commits that don't exist anymore.

You just use

```
git rebase -i
```

and then make sure to **squash** all your commits together in one clean commit or just **delete** the lines with the commits that you want to remove alltogether.

2. For the future, you should create a branch when starting a new development:

   git checkout -b newDevelopmentBranch

now do all your developments, commit and push as much as you want. You can even rebase your history; since you are the only developer on this branch (I suppose). When your branch is clean an you want to get your developments on the master branch, you can merge them:

```
git checkout master
git merge newDevelopmentBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to actually delete the commits, rather squash (merge) them

`git rebase -i` (Interactive rebase) is ideal for this

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i/

This link talks specifically about this-
http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

So, you could do (for example)

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

then `pick` and `squash` commits as required

You can even enter a new commit message, to really clean your tree up